# How do I authenticate using a service account in the Google Cloud Platform REST API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I want to make a REST API call to Google Cloud Platform using a service account key, but I am unable to figure out how to authenticate the call. Normally, I would use the provided client library and pass the key to it, but in this instance the client library does not support this particular endpoint.

This is the rest endpoint I am trying to call:
https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/admin/rest/v1/projects/export

I need to make the call from a nodejs application, so this is the corresponding client library:
https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-datastore

[The documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/admin/rest/v1/projects/export) is heavy on general concepts, but I can't find anything concrete on how to actually make the REST call with the correct credentials.

Comment: I wrote an article that shows the steps in Python: https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-creating-oauth-access-tokens-for-rest-api-calls/

Comment: Another thought might be to use the Generic Google API Client Library for JavaScript.  As I understand it ... at a loose level ... for ALL the APIs listed here ... https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/  which includes https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/admin/rest/ there is a JavaScript high level API that provides authentication and calling capabilities.

Comment: @JohnHanley That's awesome! I'm going to port that to nodejs and give that a shot now. How did you find out how to do that, if I may ask? Is there a doc somewhere that I don't know about, or is that from a general understanding of OAuth and trial and error?

Comment: @Kolban I didn't know about the JS client. Thanks for pointing it out. It seems like it is designed for the client side though, along with the corresponding  auth flows, so I don't think I can use that on the server side.

Comment: @JohnHanley I was able to get started thanks to you code and discovered the official google-auth-library that handles the OAuth flow for me. I was able to use that to make the call. I'll post the code as an answer. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @bluethings - I created my article by studying the Google Cloud client library source code. I see that you posted an answer using one of the client libraries. If you search my answers you will see other client examples that I wrote in node.js and other languages.

Answer (score 2):

I discovered that Google has the library [`google-auth-library`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs) for nodejs which handles the required OAuth flow internally. I was able to use that to successfully make the authenticated call.

This is the code:

```
const auth = await new GoogleAuth({
    keyFilename: pathToKey,
    scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
}).getClient()

const result = await auth.request({
    url: `https://datastore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/${projectId}:export`,
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(payload),
})
```

Note, this handled the authentication part. I still have to grant the right privileges to the service account to get the authorization part working.

## EDIT

Apparently there is also a [`googleapis`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client) nodejs library that provides a thin wrapper around the whole REST API. I prefer this to making the rest call directly because the library has Typescript typings that check that the payload has the right shape, etc., and I don't have to manually specify URLs. You still need the [`google-auth-library`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs) to handle auth.

```
import {google as googleapis} from 'googleapis'

const auth = await new GoogleAuth({
    keyFilename: pathToKey,
    scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
}).getClient()

const datastore = googleapis.datastore('v1')
await datastore.projects.export({
    auth,
    projectId: theProjectid,
    requestBody: payload,
})
```